# Time comeplexity difference in between inner loop and by calling function

Tags: time-complexity

This is a question regarding Complexity of algorithm. If I am creating a loop ('for' loop for instance) and want to test the primality of the values returned (after some operations definitely) in this loop and therefore, I run an inner loop. Instead of that, if I create a function to test primality and then call that function during the first loop, still, the time complexity remains same right?
And what is the complexity in both cases? How to calculate that?

Thanks

Comment: You haven't told us what you're looping over so... obviously we can't help you

Comment: I'm looping $n=i*i/5$; where $i$ is from from $1$ to $10^4$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Complexcity of a code is measured in terms of space and time. Lets try to understand the time complexcity.

Lets see one way to measure time Complexcity, it is most famous and called Big O notqtion. As per wikipedia "Big O notation is a mathematical notation that describes the limiting behavior of a function when the argument tends towards a particular value or infinity. "

Suppose there is an operation (which may be performed by few lines of code) whose single execution takes `T` units of time. Time complexcity is the function of number of input values and represents the time taken to execute the operation for those input items.

1. If the time taken is always `T` irrespective of the number of inputs then it is said to be a constant function and time complexcity is said to be *O(1)*.
2. If the time taken increases linearly with respect to the number of input then it is linear function amd time complexcity is `O(N)`

Lets see a simple example

```
public int sumOfFirstNNumbersWayOne( int n ){              
    int sum = 0;
     for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++){
           sum += i; // this loops executes as per the number n
     }
     return sum;
}


  public int sumOfFirstNNumbersWayTwo( int n ){ 
       int sum = n*(n+1)/2; // the number of times this operation is executed is independent of the input n
      return sum;
 }
```

Time complexcity of `sumOfFirstNNumbersWayOne` is O(n) and for 
`sumOfFirstNNumbersWayTwo` is O(1).

It does not matter if the operation os performed within loops or a method is called in measuring time complexcity. ( Overhead of method call, method call's entry in stack, are negligible)

```
 public int sumOfFirstNNumbersWayThree( int n ){ 
     int sum = 0;
     for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++){
           sum = sum( sum, i);
     }
     return sum;
 }

public int sum(int a , int b){ 
     return a+b;
}
```

Time compelxcity of `sumOfFirstNNumbersWayThree` is still O(n).

Similarly suppose the number of times a particular set of operations gets increased exponentially as the number of input is increased then time complexcity is said to be *exponential*.

Other famous time complexcites are `O(log(n)), O(n^2), O(nlog(n)), O(n!)`, [ `n` is the reference and it can be number of input with respect to which we want to measure the time complexcity, it can be size of the input array, number of bits of input number, number of digits of input number, length of input string, number of lines in a file, etc]